# mysql query gives different result on different servers

Tags: mysql, yii, centos5

I have the following query which runs fine on my test box but does not work on my production box. what is the problem?

```
SELECT 
    *,
    round(priceperkm * IFNULL(KMPlanned, projects.KM),
            4) AS NEWVALUE,
    round(PRICE * IFNULL(KMPlanned, projects.KM),
            2) AS TotalPriceForItem,
    SUM(((abs(FSP - LSP) + 1) * SI) / 1000) AS KM_Completed,
    round(SUM(((abs(FSP - LSP) + 1) * SI) / 1000) * PRICE,
            2) AS TotalPrice,
    round((SUM(((abs(FSP - LSP) + 1) * SI) / 1000) * PRICE) / (PRICE * IFNULL(KMPlanned, projects.KM)) * 100,
            2) AS TotalPercent
FROM
    hdb.projects
        join
    biditems ON projects.id = biditems.project_id
        join
    lookupprocess ON biditems.ITEMID = lookupprocess.biditems_id
        left join
    jobsprocesscomplete ON lookupprocess.ID = lookupprocess_id
        left join
    detailsseismic ON jobsprocesscomplete.JOBNO = detailsseismic.JOBNO
where
    projects.PROJID = 1402013
        and lookupprocess.ID = 13138
```

Error:

```
2014/02/24 18:37:06 [error] [system.db.CDbCommand] CDbCommand::() failed: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause. The SQL statement executed was: 


                .
2014/02/24 18:37:06 [error] [exception.CDbException] exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause' in /data/intranet/html/yii-1.1.14/framework/db/CDbCommand.php:543
Stack trace:
#0 /data/intranet/html/yii-1.1.14/framework/db/CDbCommand.php(377): CDbCommand->queryInternal('', 0, Array)
#1 /data/intranet/html/paradox/protected/controllers/GlobalController.php(260): CDbCommand->query()
#2 /data/intranet/html/paradox/protected/controllers/ProjectsController.php(648): GlobalController->lookupprocesstotal('1402013', Array)
#3 [internal function]: ProjectsController->actionUpdate('12768')
#4 /data/intranet/html/yii-1.1.14/framework/web/actions/CAction.php(108): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(ProjectsController), Array)
#5 /data/intranet/html/yii-1.1.14/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(47): CAction->runWithParamsInternal(Object(ProjectsController), Object(ReflectionMethod), Array)
#6 /data/intranet/html/yii-1.1.14/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#7 /data/intranet/html/yii-1.1.14/framework/web/CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
#8 /data/intranet/html/yii-1.1.14/framework/web/CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#9 /data/intranet/html/yii-1.1.14/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('update')
#10 /data/intranet/html/yii-1.1.14/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController('projects/update')
#11 /data/intranet/html/yii-1.1.14/framework/base/CApplication.php(180): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#12 /data/intranet/html/paradox/index.php(31): CApplication->run()
#13 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/sidb/index.php?r=projects/update&id=12768
HTTP_REFERER=http://intranet/sidb/index.php?r=projects/admin
```

**UPDATE**
Both servers give same result below
    SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
    +-------------------+
    | @@GLOBAL.sql_mode |
    +-------------------+
    |                   | 
    +-------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)

```
mysql> SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
+--------------------+
| @@SESSION.sql_mode |
+--------------------+
|                    | 
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'sql_mode'
    -> ;
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| sql_mode      |       | 
+---------------+-------+
```

What will happen if i add `group by lookupprocess.ID` at end of query. will it return same results?

Comment: Your poduction server has probably `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` option turned on, while test server hasn't, see this link for details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated both servers to latest mysql version available in repository. The affected server had old version, which I believe did not support the sql statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your `select` clause has both columns and aggregation functions (`sum()`).  This turns the query into an aggregation query that will return only one row, which may or may not be what you intend.  (I suspect that you actually do want to `group by` *something*.)

In any case, this uses a MySQL extension.  The extension is controlled by a system variable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.  When this is enabled, then the ANSI rules apply.  Read about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)!.

The behavior that you are seeing suggests that `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is enabled on the production server but not on the development server.  You should either enable it or disable it in both.